# Multiple mysqli prepared queries result in latest executing multiple times

Tags: php, mysqli, namespaces

So, I am working on a PHP project right now and have created a session management system with MySQL incorporated instead of using the default PHP Sessions, as it was getting too cumbersome with some functionalities. I have namespaced functions for managing the session data updation and retrieval in the database. The problem arises when I call the updation statement multiple times and the query runs every time but only with values I passed in the latest call.

```
function update_session_var($x, $var_name, 
 $var_value)
{    
    $find_session_var =
        "SELECT * FROM session_data_table
         WHERE x=?
         AND dKey=?";
    $db_conn = //mysqli_connect object ;
    $stmt = $db_conn->prepare($find_session_var);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $x, $var_name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt_var_result = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();
    $queryUse = "";
    if(mysqli_num_rows($stmt_var_result) < 1)
        $queryUse =
            "INSERT INTO session_data_table 
             (dKey, dV, x) 
             VALUES 
             (?, ?, ?)";
    else
        $queryUse =
            "UPDATE session_data_table 
             SET dKey=?,
             dV=?
             WHERE x=?
             ";
    $stmt = $db_conn->prepare($queryUse);
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $var_name, $var_value, $x);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

and I call the functions consecutively, like

```
\namespace_path\update_session_var($x, "1st", "2nd");
\namespace_path\update_session_var($x, "3rd", "4th");
```

But what actually happens is that I get two entries for the 2nd call instead of one for 1st,2nd and one for 3rd,4th.
Before the calls are made, I even check if the entries exist already, and it even gets past that check. Further, if I put a die() between the two function calls, the first works as intended. It is when they're called consecutively which is creating issues.

I have no idea why this is happening. Help, someone?

Comment: Your update query looks incorrect. Shouldn't you only be updating the `dV` value for the `x` + `dKey` combination? If I had to guess, I'd say `mysqli_num_rows($stmt_var_result) < 1` is always `false`. You might be interested in using MySQL's [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) feature

Comment: You're not very clear on the behaviour you're seeing, but locally stored values can't persist from one function call to the next. You'd be much better off defining an appropriate `UNIQUE` index on your table, and then using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` insert query.

Comment: I'm using an auto-increment unique id @miken32. What you are specifying as can't happen is exactly what is happening but instead of persisting, the value for the original call is somehow also being overridden by the arguments passed in the next call. I was wondering if this has something to do with namespacing and that may have been adding a static variable effect but seeing as how php calls are synchronous(?), that should not have been an issue either.